# How to filter Wikidata dump for a language?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdf, wikidata

I've downloaded the Wikidata truthy dump in RDF format (.nt.bz2 file). I want to limit the language of the dump to English only and generate this new filtered  dump as a new .nt file.

I've tried using parallel grep to filter lines with '@en' text, but it consumes a lot of processing time.

Is there some much faster way to generate filtered dumps? Something like using Spark?

Comment: why should Spark be faster then using parallel streaming highly efficient Unix tools? The text would have to be parsed and loaded into a JVM first. And you'd need a cluster or at least some powerful machine that runs multiple workers. Did you extract the dump before using `grep` ? You know that there are also tools like `bzgrep`? And what means long?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit late for you, but meanwhile a tool was generated to create custom dumps: https://tools.wmflabs.org/wdumps/

With this tool you can online define a language filter and then download an .nt file with only the relevant triples.